# Angularfire, firebase JSON Web Tokens - how to access to authentication data from token?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I have service in php that return token with custom data (authentication data):

```
  include_once "FirebaseToken.php";
  $secret = "***********";
  $tokenGen = new Services_FirebaseTokenGenerator($secret);
  $token = $tokenGen->createToken(array("name" => "ADMIN"),array( admin => true));
  echo $token;
```

Then in angular i have function for login:

```
adminlogin: function(){
  var token;
  $http.get("http://****").success(function(data){token=data;})
    .then(function(){
       var dataRef = new Firebase(FBURL);
         dataRef.auth(token, function(error) {
          if(error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("DISPLAY name FROM TOKEN");
          }
        });
      })
```

And after authentication i want to show name from token.
How to access to authentication data from token ?

Answer (score 1):

The token is a simple JWT format. It can be deconstructed using window.atob() in your browser. You can also [grab a polyfill](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/0.2.0/base64.min.js) for browsers which don't support atob/btoa methods. The code below is from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6231937).

```
// Helper function to extract claims from a JWT. Does *not* verify the
// validity of the token. 
// credits: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularFire.js#L370
function deconstructJWT(token) {
   var segments = token.split(".");
   if (!segments instanceof Array || segments.length !== 3) {
      throw new Error("Invalid JWT");
   }
   var claims = segments[1];
   return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(claims))));
}
```

And here is a fiddle that constructs and deconstructs Firebase tokens using this approach, to give you a working example and a simple tool for testing:

http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/embedded/result/

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to clarify. I want to read the data sent in the token but after verification by firebase. The data must be trusted. I already find solution.

Comment: Your solution is a bit circuitous, using angularFire to parse the token for you. Internally, angularFire uses the same code as the example above (which is actually taken from angularFire's internals).

Answer (score 0):

After few hours i know the answer. I mixed angularFire with Firebase.

It should be like that:

```
adminlogin: function(){
var token; var dataRef;
      $http.get("http://localhost/rubinki/php/").success(function(data){token=data;})
      .then(function(){
        angularFireAuth.login(token);
      })
    }
```

and then if you have a properly initialized angularFireAuth method, for example:

```
angularFireAuth.initialize(new Firebase(FBURL), {scope: $rootScope, name: 'auth');
```

You can access to authentication data from view like this:

```
{{auth.d.email}}
```

All data from token are in auth.d.